# Minor grid spacing seems insconsitent on the vertical axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can someone explain to my why the spacing between 0 and 200 on the vertical axis seems to be different between 200 and 400 etc.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={Time (years)},
        ylabel={Activity (Bq)},
        domain=0:2000,
        samples=100,
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        xtick={0,200,...,2000},
        ytick={0,200,...,2000},
        ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
        x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east},
        black,
        width=10cm,
        height=10cm,
        grid=both,
        minor y tick num=4,
        minor x tick num=4,
        major grid style={black, line width=1pt},
        minor grid style={black!30, line width=0.8pt},
        ]
        \def\Nzero{2000}
        \def\halfLife{432}
        \def\decayConstant{ln(2)/\halfLife}
        
        \addplot [thick] {\Nzero * exp(-\decayConstant * x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I took a liberty and to question add image of your diagram. You need to add `ymin=0`, than your image will be as you like to have.

Comment: As said by @Zarko, the minum value your y has is around 160. You got confused by the zero label which belongs to the x axis...

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved my issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is solved by comments.